# Leetcode 4sums concise solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Recently doing leetcode but encounter difficulties in this 4 sum [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/). For the `kSum` function below, I saw some of the solutions online,  passing an empty array as a parameter to store the result. I think it makes `kSum()` too many parameters.

I am thinking of refactoring `kSum()` holds a parameter of itself but not much process. It return something strange(eg. an empty array)

I would like to ask what I am missing to make my algorithm works? I think the problem may due to the second for loop which loop through `kSum(nums, i+1, ...)` ?

```
const fourSum = (nums, target) => {
    const sortedNumsArray = nums.sort((a, b) => a - b)

    return kSum(sortedNumsArray, 0, 4, target)
}

const kSum = (nums, start, k, target) => {
    const result = [];

    if( nums.length === start  || nums[nums.length - 1] * k < target || nums[start] * k > target) return result;

    if (k === 2) {
        return twoSum(nums, 0, target)
    } else {
        let shouldCheck = false;

        for (let i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (shouldCheck && nums[i] !== nums[i - 1]) {
                for (let set of kSum(nums, i + 1, k - 1, target - nums[i])) {
                    result.push([nums[i]])
                    result[result.length - 1].concat(set)
                }
            }

            shouldCheck = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

const twoSum = (nums, start, target) => {
    let left = start;
    let right = nums.length - 1
    let subResult = []

    while (left < right) {
        let sum = nums[left] + nums[right]

        if (sum === target) {
           subResult.push([nums[left++], nums[right--]])

            while (left < right && nums[left] === nums[left + 1]) { left++ }
            while (left < right && nums[right] === nums[right - 1]) { right-- }
        } else if (sum > target) {
            right--
        } else {
            left++
        }
    }

    return subResult;
}
```

Comment: You should limit your question to one question.

Comment: @trincot Sure! Just edited my question.

Comment: What language is this (it looks like js)? I am not seeing anything obviously wrong with the logic, so it might be a language/implementation issue.

Comment: *sigh* Well it doesn't help that Leetcode's problem description confusing, ambiguous and yet is still clearly wrong and contradicted by their first example.  The sloppiness of that site drive me nuts.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes you bet! It is JS. I have been struggling for a few days.